# Android Activity Finish

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, exit

I am try to add theme change option in my application.I have a main activity called timeline.And from there user can go to themechange activity can change theme.It changes the theme of the themechange activity but not the timeline i.e mainactivity.When i reload the timeline activity again i can see the chnage.

Then i add the following code to save button in themechange activity to reload timeline activity

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            Intent i = new Intent(BackgroundChange.this, TimeLine.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(i);
            Intent k = new Intent(BackgroundChange.this,
                    SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(k);

        }
    });
```

and it works well.

But when i exit my application and start again i can see the timeline acivity which was before themechage.

i use following code for exit application

```
 exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

and if i exit again i can see the changed timeline.I want to clear all acitivites when exit my application.I can not retain any previous activity after exit. Now what can i do?Please give me a suggestion..

Comment: use:                                                                                              **public void onClick(View v) {       
         finish();
         System.exit(0);
     }**

Answer (score 2):

In the exit,

```
exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimeLine.class); //This will finish all activities except TimeLine
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                            intent.putExtra("exit", true);
                            startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

In timeline's OnCreate,

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("exit", false))
 finish(); //This will finish your main activity
```

Answer (score 0):

However if you use this.finish() it works.Remove all the intent and just use "this.finish()". Surely it
will work. if it's not working, then use System.exit(0) after finish().

Answer (score 0):

You can use noHistory="true" for your Activity in manifest file